$f : \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$ ; $f (x + y) = f (x)\cdot f (y) \,\, \forall x,y \in \mathbb{Q}\,$ and $f(1) = 10$. Prove $f$ is bijective.

Let $f : \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$ be a function such that $f (x + y) = f (x)\cdot f (y) \,\, \forall x,y \in \mathbb{Q}\,$ and $f(1) = 10$. Prove $f$ is bijective.

I have approached it like this:
$$ f(x) =: e^{ax} \quad \left[\text{ Example of } f (x + y) = f (x)\cdot f (y)\right]$$
Now, $$f(1) =10 \implies e^a = 10\implies a = \ln 10$$
Hence, $$f(x) =e^{x\ln10}=10^x$$
If we look the function $f(x)$ is strictly increasing function and surjective(one-one) function. But,
$$\mathscr{R}(f) = \mathbb{Q}^+\ne \mathbb{Q}$$
Therefore, $f$ is neither onto nor bijective.
I think taking an example and analyzing it is not sufficient. Can someone give me the general way.  Thanking You.

$f(x)=[f(\frac x 2)]^{2} \ge 0$ so $f$  cannot be  surjective.

@geetha290krm What's worse, the function can't even exist :)

For what it's worth:  if there is any $x_0$ for which $f(x_0)=0$, then the function is identically $0$, as $f(x)=f(x_0+x-x_0)=f(x_0)\times f(x-x_0)=0$.  Just as another way to look at it.  So a surjective example would be constant, an obvious contradiction.

The function you propose cannot exist. This is because $$10=f(1)=f\left(\frac 12 + \frac 12\right) = f\left(\frac12\right)\cdot f\left(\frac12\right)$$
which means that $f\left(\frac12\right)=\pm\sqrt{10}\neq \mathbb Q$.

Thus technically, any function satisfying the requirement is indeed bijective.

@anankElpis Technically correct is, as we all know, the best kind of correct :D.

Thanks. I should do nothing just look there is no possible function -> It is bijective function any way.
